# Windows system message constants in C++

Tags: c++, windows-messages

I was looking at some various sample code for processing mouse click events in C++ using a Windows system message hook, and thought that this would be a great way to process key presses that are usually only sent to the system, such as CTRL, ALT, SHIFT, etc. I was wondering if someone has a complete list of input constants (like `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`) or knows where to find one. Specifically, I would like to know which message constants are for keyboard inputs.
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can grep the Windows header files for them?

Comment: Windows.h has them. What C++ compiler/IDE are you using?

Comment: I will be using Qt and VS 2010. I said will, be cause I don't have them installed yet, because I tried to install Xubuntu (a Linux distrubution) and my boot sector died. X(

Comment: Probably VS for Windows projects though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the link included in Donatalo's answer, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) goes to the list of keyboard constants - Virtual key codes, that I think you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

These constants are in `winuser.h`, which is part of the Microsoft Platform SDK. If you have Visual Studio installed, you may also have the SDK installed (look inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows`). If not, you can download the latest version (v7.1) [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35AEDA01-421D-4BA5-B44B-543DC8C33A20).